# git stash pop: avoiding stash drop and un-staging steps

Tags: git, git-merge, git-stash, merge-conflict-resolution

Sometimes when running `git stash pop` there are merge conflicts that need to be resolved. This happens a lot when I have to stash/pop before/after switching branches.

The conflicts are no problem to deal with, but this has two annoying side effects:

1. All changes coming from the stash are now staged and have to be unstaged
2. `stash@{0}` is not dropped and has to be dropped manually

Looking for suggestions on how to make this process a little smoother.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using stash as a means for you to switch branches and then just apply the stash, I can recommend using the -m option for checkout

```
git checkout -m master
```

Will switch to master and perform a merge of your changed files. This way you don't need to do

```
git stash
git checkout master
git stash pop
git reset HEAD .
```

Comment: Yes, but doesn't merging after a `stash pop` create a merge commit? I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: I'm trying to tell you that you don't have to use stash at all if you just want to switch between branches. Just do checkout with -m option and you are set.

Answer (score -1):

Use `git stash drop` - or `git stash clear` if you don't have anymore stashes to clear the stash you saved. You'll need to `git reset --hard` if you don't want anything from the stash or `git reset HEAD .` to clear what you staged.

I miss-read the initial question. Corrected now.

Hope this helps.